# create a function that raises a base price by 10% based off of square footage in increments of 500sqft React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calculator, create-react-app

Im very new to software development but over the past year i've been self taught and managed to create an AWS driven React js platform app that can log you in, book appointments, display completed services, and more.

I am trying to calculate the price of our services based off of the property square footage. Its may be a little confusing, but please try to bear with me!! Ill try my best to explain. I've searched everywhere for the past 2 months on how to do this and im finally breaking down to ask the question. I was avoiding asking this for quite some time because I am not very fluent in software development language, so I apologize ahead of time if the question does not make sense!

I am using stripe api for the transactions.

The formula looks something like this....

**Base square footage:** less than or equal to 2000 sqft

**Base Price:** $149.99

The **Base Price** goes **UP** **10%** **for every 500 sqft** over the base square footage of 2000sqft.

so if the property is 2000sqft or less, than the calculated price should be $149.99.

if the property is 2500 sqft, than the calculated price should be $164.98 as it goes up 10% for every 500 sqft after the base square footage (2000sqft).

if the property is 3000 sqft , than the calculated price should be $179.98 as it goes up 10% two times, (%20) from the original base price at $149.99.

Im having a pretty hard time trying to figure out how to go about this...

If anyone could please possibly point me in the right starting direction, or point me to any resources that could help me expand my knowledge on applying some logic to this, that would be extremely appreciated!!

Comment: is the price compounded? As in, is it always a $14.99 increase for every extra 500 sqft? or is it compounded where you add 10% from the previous price for each 500sqft  over?

Comment: you're focusing your time in the wrong place my man, i recommend going back to the basics with JS before worrying about the AWS deployment.

Comment: @AndrewLohr thanks for asking, Im sorry for not clarifying that!  So every 500 sqft added is compounding the 10% mark up percentage. so if it jumps from 2000 sqft to 3000 sqft, that would be two (500sqft) marking up the base price now 20%.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let base_price = 149.99;
if(sqft > 2000){
   let overage = sqft - 2000;
   let percentage = Math.ceil(overage % 500) * 10;
   base_price += base_price * percentage;
}
```